# Does startService always create a new Service or is the Intent sent to the existing one?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am developing an Android application where I start a Service via an Intent. The service opens a connection and reports its success to an Activity. Afterwars the user shall be able to start a data transmission via Button click. This is also done by the service.

Is it the best way to send another Intent to my service? And does a service always exist only once or is another instance created of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how many times you start the service, the service will be started only once and at any time only one instance of the service is created. If you start the service multiple times using `startService()` method then `onStartCommand()` method will be called multiple times.

The best way to communicate the service from the activity is to bind the service(bounded service).

Comment: When I use a bound service and call methods on the service instance from my activity then, are those methods executed inside the main thread or inside a separate Thread? And does that depend on the kind of Service? I read, that IntentServices run in a separate worker thread and normal services not.

Comment: Ya your right... normal services run on the main thread only. Bound service is nothing but a normal service...so it runs on main thread.

Comment: But it is also possible to bind to an IntentService, right? Are commands to that service executed from the main thread or from the service thread?

Comment: If you bind the intent service the commands to that service will run on main thread only